# In operator from Python in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS however i have some Python background.I'm developing a web-app using flask however in some of my HTML templates i have to use JS `<script>`. So i have a dropdown list of options, which is a datalist. Is there a way to say "if input_value in datalist then"?

I think it should look sth like

```
if (input_value in datalist){
    do some stuff
}
```

Idk how to say in though.

i have tried searching for an answer using scripts from ES6 and ES5 however they dont really work for me.

I've tried after finding an answer on the same issue using .indexOf saying that if its -1 then it doesn't exist in the list. However i get this error: datalist.indexOf is not a function.

Here is part of the js code:

```
var selectedClientInput = document.getElementById("selected-client");
var selectedClient = selectedClientInput.value;

var datalist = document.getElementById("clients");
var options = datalist.getElementsByTagName("option");

if (options.indexOf(selectedClientInput) == -1){
    throw new Error("Please select a client from the dropdown list.");
}
```

Comment: Your `options` variable is not a JavaScript array, it's a browser NodeList.

Comment: So wouldn't `selectedClient` have no value? unclear what you are actually tryng to accomplish. Maybe html would help.

Comment: To tack onto Pointy's comment: wrap `options` as [`Array.from(options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) so that you can use [all the Array functions JS has to offer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: The JS equivalent to `something in array` is `array.includes(something)`. But `options` is not an array, so you need to convert it to an array, e.g. `if (Array.from(options).includes(selectedClientInput))`

Comment: @epascarello after the user clicks a button the selected client gets the value that the user has input

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina you cannot, really. In JS `in` will check object properties, which for arrays are the indexes.

Comment: `[...options].includes(selectedClientInput)`

Comment: @Barmar do i have to declare the Array before using it? because it doesnt work

Comment: This code seems really complicated. If you want to tell if the user has selected anything from a dropdown, just check `datalist.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pointy @Barmar and @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I managed to get to the solution. As they pointed I wasn't using an array but a nodelist so I just have to convert it into an array and use its functions.

Here is the completed code:

```js
var selectedClientInput = document.getElementById("selected-client");
var selectedClient = selectedClientInput.value;

var datalist = document.getElementById("clients");
var options = datalist.getElementsByTagName("option");

if (Array.from(options).some(option => option.value === selectedClient)){

    do something ; 
}
else {

    throw new Error("Please select a client from the dropdown list.");

}
```

As you can see the options NodeList has been converted to an array using:

```
Array.from(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML, here is another option. You can use `querySelector` of `datalist` to see if an option exists with the value from `selectedClient`.

```js
const selectedClientInput = document.getElementById("selected-client");
let selectedClient = selectedClientInput.value;

const datalist = document.getElementById("clients");
let options = datalist.querySelector("option[value='" + selectedClient + "']");

if(!options){
  console.log("Please select a client from the dropdown list.")
}
else{
  console.log("Found!");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="selected-client" value="client1">
<input list="clients" id="clientList" />
<datalist id="clients">
  <option value="client1"></option>
  <option value="client12"></option>
  <option value="client13"></option>
  <option value="client14"></option>
  <option value="client15"></option>
</datalist>
```